# ARIA and WCAG 2.0 success criteria

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

Please correct me if I'm getting this wrong. If I understand it correctly I don't have to use `aria-hidden` for elements that basically are available in the source of the document, however are not always shown.

For example, an image slider or a menu or tooltip that are there in the document source(basically they are available), but not always presented visually to the user on the display.

Because it sounds weird to me I don't have to use ARIA for this things in order to meet WCAG 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `aria-hidden` to meet WCAG. You *can* use it to meet WCAG. You can *also* use it and accidentally violate WCAG.

If you want to visually display something but hide it from assistive technology (screen readers in this case), then `aria-hidden` may be the best option.

If you want to hide something visually *and* from assistive technology, then skip the `aria-hidden` and just style it with `display:none;`.

If you want to hide an element's native semantics (such as legacy layout tables) but otherwise display everything within, then `role=presentation` is the way to go.

Importantly, do not use `aria-hidden` to hide something that otherwise needs to receive focus or be interactive (per the [Fourth Rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#fourth-rule-of-aria-use)). Doing that would violate WCAG.

So, for example, if you have a tool-tip style design element that is hidden with `display:none;` when not in use, skip the `aria-hidden`. It is just extra noise and an additional place your code can become inaccessible if you fail to update it with the visual style.

Comment: So it will pass the wcag2 if I'll use `display:none` and `display:block`. BTW: how should I inform the user when I switch from `display:none` to `display:block` and focus on it? I mean is there any rules for this? Because I think if the user is using AT it may cause problems to him. Like: "where the hell is this coming from?". Thanks, aardrian! :)

Comment: No, just because you use `display` styles does not mean it will or will not pass a particular WCAG SC. Just as you do not necessarily need `aria-hidden` to pass a particular WCAG SC. What I am saying is that you are not required to use `aria-hidden` just to pass a SC. As for your second question, you need to manage focus well and place it on the rigth element. Ideally you warn the user accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, because the WCAG 2.0 isn't about specific techniques, but yet, in cases like this you MUST use something to inform the user about hidden/visible status, right? So the only ways are the `aria-hidden` or `display:none/block`. Correct?  As about the warning the user accordingly, I couldn't find anything except the `live-region`. I assume I need to warn him with this? For example, the when navigation menu is revealed, I should move the focus to the first link in it and also use `aria-live=polite` for the entire menu block. Correct? :)

Comment: No, you do not need to inform the user that something is hidden. You can also hide something like a form element with the `disabled` attribute, so what you use depends on the context. Warning the user does not require live regions, again it depends on context. Opening what is clearly a navigatoin menu does not require a live region, just focus management. Alerting the user of errors on the page may require a live region.